# How do I add font-size properly in my css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a font-size change to a specific p in my CSS.

I made a new class `.mainbg p { xxxx }` but this doesn't work. Whats strange is that the same class worked when I added text-shadow for that p. I don't understand why it wont work for this.

```
<section aria-label="home" class="mainbg" id="home">

    <!-- intro -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="overlay-main v-align">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">

        <h1 class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="300">LOUIS WALLACE CONSTRUCTION</h1>
        <div class="onStep" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-time="600" id="slidertext">
          <h3 class="main-text">Oroville General Contractor</h3>
          <h3 class="main-text">Over A Decade Of Experience</h3>
          <h3 class="main-text">All Phases Of Construction</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="onStep" data-animation="animbouncefall" data-time="900" >No matter how large or small the project, we ensure that your project is completed with precision and professionalism. We take pride in our quality craftsmanship, our attention to detail, and our open line of communication with each and every customer. With each project, we understand that our role is about more than simply putting up walls — it’s about ensuring that your vision is turned into a reality.
```

Comment: Can you add your css what you have tried earlier

Comment: I think you forgot your css. Please include it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems another default CSS overriding your P tag styling.

Use `!important` in your CSS declaration.

e.g:

```
.mainbg p { 
   font-size:12px !important;
 }
```